# NVMe SSD's bandwidth decreases when increasing the number of I/O queues

Tags: operating-system, storage, hardware, solid-state-drive, nvme

As far as I have learned from all the relevant articles about NVMe SSDs, one of NVMe SSDs' benefits is multiple queues. Leveraging multiple NVMe I/O queues, NVMe bandwidth can be greatly utilized.
However, what I have found from my own experiment does not agree with that.

I want to do parallel 4k-granularity sequential reads from an NVMe SSD. I'm using Samsung 970 EVO Plus 250GB. I used FIO to benchmark the SSD. The command I used is:

```
fio --size=1000m --directory=/home/xxx/fio_test/ --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --name=4kseqread --bs=4k --iodepth=64 --rw=read --numjobs 1/2/4 --group_reporting
```

And below is what I got testing 1/2/4 parallel sequential reads:

numjobs=1: 1008.7MB/s

numjobs=2: 927 MB/s

numjobs=4: 580 MB/s

Even if will not increasing bandwidth, I expect increasing I/O queues would at least keep the same bandwidth as the single-queue performance. The bandwidth decrease is a little bit counter-intuitive. What are the possible reasons for the decrease?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting filesystem contention because all your files are in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to highlight 3 reasons why you may see the issue:

1. Effective Queue Depth is too high,
2. Capacity under the test is limited to 1GB only,
3. Drive Precondition

First, parameter --iodepth=X is specified per Job. It means in your last experiment (--iodepth=64 and --numjobs=4) effective Queue Depth is 4x64=256. This may be too high for your Drive. Based on the vendor specification of your 250GB Drive, 4KB Random Read should show 250 KIOPS (1GB/s) for the Queue Depth of 32. By this Vendor is stating that QD32 is quite optimal for your Drive operation in order to reach best performance. If we start to increase QD, then commands will start aggregating and waiting in the Submission Queue. It does not improve performance. Vice Versa it will start to eat system resources (CPU, memory) and will degrade the throughput.

Second, limiting capacity under test to such a small range (1GB) can cause lot of collisions inside SSD. It is the situation when Reads will hit the same Media Physical Read Unit (aka Die aka LUN). In such situation new Reads will have to wait for previous one to complete. Increase of the testing capacity to entire Drive or at least to 50-100GB should minimize the collisions.

Third, in order to get performance numbers as per specification, Drive needs to be preconditioned accordingly. For the case of measuring Sequential and Random Reads it is better to use Full Drive Sequential Precondition. Command bellow will perform 128KB Sequential Write at QD32 to the Entire Drive Capacity.

> fio --size=100% --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --name=128KB_SEQ_WRITE_QD32 --bs=128k --iodepth=4 --rw=write --numjobs=8